# Assign value to parent golang structure field

Tags: go

There are two situations:

```
type A struct {
    A_FIELD  string
}
type B struct {
    A
    B_FIELD  string
}

func main() {
    b := &B{
        A_FIELD: "aaaa_field",
        B_FIELD: "bbbb_field",
    } 
}
```

And

```
type A struct {
    A_FIELD  string
}
type B struct {
    A
    B_FIELD  string
}

func main() {
    b := &B{}
    b.A_FIELD = "aaaa_field"
    b.B_FIELD = "bbbb_field"
    fmt.Printf("Good!")
}
```

Why the second one is working, but the first one is not? I receive compile time exceptions. How should I change first one to work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Why the second one is working, but the first one is not?

Because

```
b.A_FIELD = "aaaa_field"
```

is actually

```
b.A.A_FIELD = "aaaa_field"
```

in disguise.

> How should I change first one to work?

```
func main() {
    b := &B{
        A: A{
            A_FIELD: "aaaa_field",
        },
        B_FIELD: "bbbb_field",
    }
}
```

You should read [how embedding work](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#embedding) on Effective Go.